# Favorite tags easy to find when in a tag view of questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

When I surf Stack Overflow I usually click on one of the favorite tags which I've set up earlier. Ok - it shows most recent question on the topic. What is annoying that I cannot move from one favorite tag to another with one click easily, since I've been just simply hitting the 'go back' button in the browser, then choosing another favorite tag.  I've now found that the favorite tags move from the top to way down the right column once you're "in" a favorite tag.

Could we have it so that when we click into a favorite tag, it keeps the favorite tag list at the top (right underneath the chosen tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good idea, but until they implement it (if) you may have to get a Greasemonkey script written for it.

Comment: lol - I am blind - this is official - but to dig a bit more - can I move it a little bit higher?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to make that a feature-request.

Comment: ok, assuming your response, there is no way to set up my `account look` to move `fav tags` higher at the page. Thanks @Lance

Comment: Humbly agree with edit, sorry for inconvenience and will search google for the script

Comment: It's critical in Meta to get things worded and laid out right so you get proper consideration of your FR.